# IsolatedStorageFile.AvailableFreeSpace - Returns massive value

Tags: c#, .net, isolatedstoragefile

According to Microsoft documentation IsolatedStorage.AvailableFreeSpace property returns the available free space for isolated storage, in bytes ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorage.availablefreespace?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

When I get this property's value on my computer it returns this: 9223372036854773759 bytes

Can anyone explain me from where this value comes from? My hard drive has 500GB and this is the equivalent to 8589934592GB.

Comment: That number is pretty close to [the maximum value of a `long`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2), the difference being `2048`, which is itself a power of 2. So it seems like it would be an error of some kind, but that's all I can really say.

Comment: The `2048` is due to the fact that I had already written some files on the Isolated Store that I was querying for the AvailableFreeSpace.